# Atom Editor Red Lines Appearing Near Project Tree

Tags: atom-editor

I've been using Atom Editor for a while now and just recently noticed something new...there are a series of red vertical lines appearing on both sides of my current window (see attached image). Has anyone seen this? Apologies if this is something obvious, but Google and SO don't offer up any help. Thanks[image: ![red lines appearing in Atom]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJjBA.png)

Comment: If you launch Atom with `atom --safe`, does this still happen? One of the packages you use may have a compatibility issue with the recent update.

Comment: Thanks for helping Dan, looks like I still have this issue when I open it up in safe mode too. If I open up a new blank window, there are no lines. But if I open up another older project, the lines appear then as well...

Comment: I might suggest taking this one to discuss.atom.io.

Comment: Thanks, just posted on there as well!

Comment: What packages do you have?